# update fields and table from database based on drop down menu selection on asp.new MVC without refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to update my student details based on the ID that is selected from the drop-down menu. I am using ASP.net MVC.  I am very new to MVC and coding so please dumb down your answer as much as possible :)

I think ajax is involved someone but I would really appreciate if someone could give me some provide some example code so I know how to get started If someone could help that would be very much  appreciated -

[This is a screen shot of the page I am creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsjHz.png) 
**Index Code Below**

`@model ResultModel
@using WebApplication3.Models`

`@{
    Layout = null;
}`

```
            <div class="container">
                <div id="flashMessage">
                   New Student Details!
                </div>
                <form>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Please Choose Student</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="StudentName">

                            <!--Drop down menu-->

                            @foreach (var item in Model.Student)
                            {
                            <option>@item.StudentNumber</option> }

                        </select>
                    </div>

                    </form>
                    <!---------------->



                <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />



                <!--   Student information form      -->
                <h4 >Student information</h4>
                <p id="cat">This will display the students information based on what is selected from the drop down menu</p>
                <code>SELECT `title`,`first name`,`surname` FROM `STUDENT REGISTER` WHERE `Student number` = 'OPTION SELECTED' </code>
                <form method="post">

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Person n">

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="student Name">

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Surname</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Surname">

                    </div>

                    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />



                    <!--   Student notes      -->
                    <h4 id="test">Student Notes</h4>
                    <p>This will display all the notes for that studend - these need to have edit button within the table to edit the fields but also have option for drop</p>
                   <code>SELECT `Date of note`,`Staff Member`,`notes` FROM `student Notes` WHERE `Student number` = option selected </code>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <table class="table table-striped" id="myTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">date</th>
                                <th scope="col">Note ID</th>
                                <th scope="col">Notes</th>
                                <th scope="col">Staff ID</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>




                                @foreach (var item in Model.Notes)
                                {
                                <tr>


                                  <td>@item.User</td>
                                    <td> @item.Notes</td>
                                    <td> @item.Id</td>

                                    <td> @item.Staff</td>

                                </tr>
                                }


                            </tbody>

                        </table>

                    <br />  <br /><br /><br />


                    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="Delete Student">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="Edit Student">

                </form>


   </div>     



    <div></div>




    <!--   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/core.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->


    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>





    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#flashMessage").hide();






        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#StudentName").change(function () {




                const sSname = document.getElementById("StudentName").value

                $('#title').val("Should Display title");
                $('#firstname').val("Should Display first Name");
                $('#surname').val("Should display last name");





                  //testing jquery - no longer in use just keeping for refrence.
                  // $("#test").text("Hello world!"); //   alert("Selected value is : " + document.getElementById("StudentName").value);     // $("#test").hide();
                  // $("#flashMessage").slideDown(1000).delay(2000).slideUp(1000);

              });



        });




        //change date to sort by dd/mm/YYYY
        jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
            "date-uk-pre": function (a) {
                if (a == null || a == "") {
                    return 0;
                }
                var ukDatea = a.split('/');
                return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
            },

            "date-uk-asc": function (a, b) {
                return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
            },

            "date-uk-desc": function (a, b) {
                return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
            }
        });

        //select the the tabe and field where the formating is allplied
        $('#myTable').dataTable({
            columnDefs: [
                { type: 'date-uk', targets: 0 }
            ]
        });



    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make ajax call on dropdown change event

```
$("#dropdownid").change(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: $('#hdnPath').val() + '/Controller/TestActionmethod',
    data: {
        dropdownid: $("#dropdownid").val()
    },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "json"
});
```

return the same view for TestActionmethod with ViewModel parameter and it will work.
Something like this

```
return View("viewName", Viewmodel );
```

Comment: what should I be putting in here `#hdnPath`

Comment: @Request.ApplicationPath of your homepage view